# C: copy a char *pointer to another

Tags: c, arrays, string, pointers

i have some trouble with a simple copy function:

```
void string_copy(char *from, char *to) {

    while ((*to++ = *from++) != '\0')
        ;
}
```

It takes two pointers to strings as parameters, it looks ok but when i try it i have this error:

```
Segmentation fault: 11
```

This is the complete code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void string_copy(char *from, char *to);

int main() {
    char *from = "Hallo world!";
    char *to;
    string_copy(from,to);
    return 0;
}
```

Thank you all

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your problem is with the destination of your copy: it's a `char*` that has not been initialized. When you try copying a C string into it, you get undefined behavior.

You need to initialize the pointer

```
char *to = malloc(100);
```

or make it an array of characters instead:

```
char to[100];
```

If you decide to go with `malloc`, you need to call `free(to)` once you are done with the copied string.

Answer (score 5):

You need to allocate memory for `to`. Something like:

```
char *to = malloc(strlen(from) + 1);
```

Don't forget to free the allocated memory with a `free(to)` call when it is no longer needed.

Comment: `malloc` size looks good - perhaps add a note to `free` after `string_copy`

Comment: `strlen` return value does not include the NUL character. So +1 is to ensure that there is an extra byte to store the NUL which is needed to form a valid string in C.

Answer (score 1):

In this program

```
#include <stdio.h>

void string_copy(char *from, char *to);

int main() {
    char *from = "Hallo world!";
    char *to;
    string_copy(from,to);
    return 0;
}
```

pointer `to` has indeterminate value. As result the program has undefined behavior.

Also function `string_copy`  has a wrong interface. It says that it does not guarantees that string pointed to by `from` will not be changed.

Also there is a common convention in C that functions that deal with strings usually return pointer to the destination string.

The function should be declared like

```
char * string_copy( const char *from, char *to );
^^^^^^              ^^^^^
```

Its definition could look like

```
char * string_copy( const char *from, char *to ) 
{
    for ( char *p = to; ( *p = *from ) != '\0'; ++p, ++from )
    {
        ;
    }

    return to;
}
```

And the program could look like

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include >stdlib.h>

char * string_copy( const char *from, char *to );

int main( void ) 
{
    char *from = "Hallo world!";
    char *to;

    to = malloc( strlen( from ) + 1 );

    puts( string_copy( from, to ) );

    free( to );

    return 0;
}

char * string_copy( const char *from, char *to ) 
{
    for ( char *p = to; ( *p = *from ) != '\0'; ++p, ++from )
    {
        ;
    }

    return to;
}
```

Take into account that you may not use pointer `to` declared like

```
    char *from = "Hallo world!";
    char *to   = "Hello everybody!";
```

in the function because string literals are immutable.

Comment: Hi i took the code for string_copy from "The c programing language" by Brian ecc. I don't understand why you need const in the signature of string_copy. Thank you

Comment: @Francesco If there is no const qualifier then the client of the function  can not be sure that the string pointed to by pointer from will not be changed inside the function.